# Xamarin Forms FlyoutPage wtih Binding Problems

Tags: xamarin, binding, flyout

I am making a Xamarin Forms app with FlyoutPage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage).

I made all the pages and menu buttons etc.

Now i wanted to use binding in the menu but can't find a way.

```
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:FlyoutPageItem}">
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="{Binding NewContacts}" IconSource="contacts.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ContactsPage}" />
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="{Binding NewTodo}" IconSource="todo.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:TodoListPage}" />
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="{Binding NewReminder}" IconSource="reminders.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ReminderPage}" />
            </x:Array>
```

But always get error:
XamlC error XFC0009: No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Title", or mismatching type between value and property.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: like the error says, `Title` is not a bindable property.  `FlyoutPageItem` is a local class defined in the sample, so you could modify it to suit your purposes

Comment: As json mentioned, you have to define the custom property in the model , pls refer to the class : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/Navigation/FlyoutPage/FlyoutPageNavigation/FlyoutPageItem.cs

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have the class like the sample but can’t bind in the array.

Comment: Have you tried the official project?

Comment: Not the entire project. But tried with a big part of it. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a basic , minimal, reproducible project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

https://github.com/karluz79/Flyout1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening because you're trying to bind a property with another property , this is incorrect.

Normally we create binding between **Target** and **source** .

The **target** is the object (and property, defined as BindableProperty) on which the data binding is set.

The **source** is the object (and property) referenced by the data binding.

However here you are trying to bind **source** to another **source** ,this breaks the principle of mvvm binding .

As a ugly workaround you can define `FlyoutPageItem.Title` as below

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Title", typeof(string), typeof(FlyoutPageItem), "");
public string Title
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
}
```

And change the binding path inside xaml

```cs
 Title="Menu"
 x:Name="Self">

<x:Array Type="{x:Type res:FlyoutPageItem}">
    <res:FlyoutPageItem Title="{Binding Source={x:Reference Self.AnyString} ,Path=BindingContext}" IconSource="Icons/door_light.png" TargetType="{x:Type views:DoorPage}" />
```

**But this is not recommended.**

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Please tell me if this is politicaly correct.

ViewModel:

```
 public string CompanyTitle => "CompanyTitleString";
 public string ContactsTitle => "ContactsTitleString";
 public string AboutTitle => "AboutTitleString";

    public List<FlyoutPageItem> flyoutPageItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<FlyoutPageItem>
                {
                    new FlyoutPageItem {
                        Title=CompanyTitle,
                        IconSource="company_light.png",
                        TargetType= typeof(CompanyPage)
                    },
                    new FlyoutPageItem {
                        Title=ContactsTitle,
                        IconSource="contacts_light.png",
                        TargetType= typeof(ContactsPage)
                    },
                    new FlyoutPageItem {
                        Title=AboutTitle,
                        IconSource="about_light.png",
                        TargetType= typeof(AboutPage)
                    }
                };
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
        <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding flyoutPageItems}">
```

EDIT: Updated the GitHub